# Run the opentripplanner project on local machine

Tags: openstreetmap, opentripplanner

I have cloned the git code of open tripplanner. Also build it using maven tool but not able to run it.

Specify the command or the entry point to run the code on local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven build process creates an executable jar file which you can then run with the command:

`java -jar <file.jar>`

With a little looking around, I found this minimal OpenTripPlanner usage example which gives you step by step directions to getting it up and running:
https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/Minimal-Introduction

Comment: After following the steps getting error while running server
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/otp/graphs/Graph.obj (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
 at org.opentripplanner.routing.impl.GraphServiceFileImpl.loadGraph(GraphServiceFileImpl.java:160) [otp.jar:1.1]
 at org.opentripplanner.routing.impl.GraphServiceFileImpl.registerGraph(GraphServiceFileImpl.java:233) [otp.jar:1.1]